# Cascade Delete Fails right after I delete relationship data from Many-to-Many table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I manually delete relationship data from a many-to-many entity, and save all changes. I can leave my page then come back and do a cascade delete without issue, but if i do a cascade delete right after i delete the relationship data, i get the error:

**System.InvalidOperationException: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.**

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WillCascadeOnDelete while creating model for Entity Framework. Example:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Proposal>()
           .HasMany(Proposal=> proposal.Responses)
           .WithRequired(response => response.Proposal)
           .HasForeignKey(response => response.ProposalId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `OBject.Remove(datatoremove);` for your delete operation. CascadeonDelete requires Fluent API.

See also [Deleting orphans with Entity Framework](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/06/02/deleting-orphans-with-entity-framework/) for reference.